# How old was Binyamin when he and his brothers went down to meet Yosef

Tags: torah-study, tanach, commentaries, yosef, genesis-bereishith

Just like the title reads. Citing the interaction between the brothers and Yosef in Egpyt during the famine retold in Bereishit 42-44, I am curious to know if any mefarshim comment on the age of Binyamin when he stands in front of Yosef - especially because he is repeatedly referred to as a na'ar.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97761/why-is-benjamin-referred-to-as-a-youth

Answer (score 4):

According to The Jewish Timeline Encyclopedia, Binyamin was born on 11 Cheshvan, 2208 from creation.

The Famine began in 2235 and Yaakov took the family down in 2238 so the events of the brothers' looking for Yosef and then standing before him must have taken place in the 2237/8 range, making Binyamin about 30.

Comment: And, he seems to have had _ten_ kids at the time.